# RollOverGraph not working on line chart

Tags: amcharts

I am trying to implement the example found [here](http://www.amcharts.com/tips/dimming-graphs-one-currently-rolled/) but for a line chart instead of a bar chart. The rollOverGraph event is never fired.

Answer (score 0):

`rollOverGraph` **does** get triggered on hovering on line graphs. To make it easier to roll over, you might increase the [`lineThickness`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#lineThickness), though.

Also, speaking about this particular demo, it manipulates `fillOpacity` of the graph. There's no "fill" on line graphs, so this might give you impression that the event is not firing. It is, but it's manipulating the parameter which does not affect appearance of the line.

Try changing the `strokeOpacity` instead:

```
function setOpacity( graph, opacity ) {
  var className = "amcharts-graph-" + graph.id;
  var items = document.getElementsByClassName( className );
  if ( undefined === items )
    return;
  for ( var x in items ) {
    if ( "object" !== typeof items[x] )
      continue;
    var path = items[x].getElementsByTagName( "path" )[ 0 ];
    if ( undefined !== path )
        path.style.strokeOpacity = opacity;
  }
}
```

Here's an [updated demo](http://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/5594a98dd94a00607b777dc9ddd49b5f).

Comment: I added a console print at the beginning of the listener methods and they are not being called. In my example I am using a cursor object. Would this by chance be the issue? Also my chart is a stacked area.

Comment: Here is a similar example of my chart. https://www.amcharts.com/demos/stacked-area/#theme-light

Comment: I don't think that fill or cursor can prevent those event from firing. Must be something else. Are you using the most recent version of the charts?

Comment: I downloaded it on Tuesday so i would think its updated. I also tried to update the chart on code pin from this link https://www.amcharts.com/demos/stacked-area/# but I couldnt get it to change the color of the filled area

Comment: I took the demo you linked to and just added `rollOverGraph` event. It fires perfectly fine: http://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/a83f6d966c20c8ecb2f882991cd8a4b0 I'm not sure what you are doing wrong, but troubleshooting like this is a bit out of SO scope. Pls contact@amcharts.com directly

Comment: the event fires but I am unable to change the opacity of the fill area or whatever the stacked color portion is called.